# Interact with a continuously mutable object

Tags: scala

I have an object, lets call it a finite state machine (FSM) that returns with every input given, an updated clone of itself.

```
case class FSM(...){
  def runInput(q:String):(FSM, String) = ...
}
```

How can I continuously run inputs from keyboard for example through it in an idiomatic way ?

```
var fsm = FSM('...')

while(true) {
  val i = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
  val res = fsm.runInput(i)
  fsm = res._1
  println(res._2)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan's answer is good.  For bonus points, you can replace explicit recursion with the appropriate abstraction.  In this case, `Iterator.iterate` is an abstraction for applying a function to its previous result.

Something like

```
def cycle(fsm: FSM) = {
    val newInput = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    val (next, result) = fsm.runInput(newInput)
    println(result)
    next
}
```

and

```
Iterator.iterate(initialFSM)(cycle)
```

gives you an infinite sequence.  It's lazy, of course, so you have to do something to force it to compute.  Asking for its `size` works.

If your FSM has a recognizable stop state, you can use `takeWhile` to terminate when you reach it.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion.

```
def doWork(fsm: FSM): FSM = {
  val i = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
  val (newFsm, result) = fsm.runInput(i)
  println(result)
  doWork(newFSM)
}
```

Comment: do you need to annotate that method with `@tailrec` to avoid stackoverflow problems?

Comment: @Atreys, you misunderstand the purpose/function of the `@tailrec` annotation. It doesn't alter what the compiler produces, it simply stops the compilation if the annotated method is not tail recursive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification